# PROJ pipeline not working in python

Tags: python, gdal, proj

I am using `gdalwarp` in the commandline as so

```
gdalwarp -ct "+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=uk_os_OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.tif +step +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84" C:/testin.tif C:/test/out.tif
```

This command runs perfectly and gives the intended output.
However, when I try to do this in python I get the error

`ERROR: ('Cannot instantiate pipeline +proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=uk_os_OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.tif +step +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84',)`

My code looks like so:

```
try:
            kwargs = {'coordinateOperation': "+proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=uk_os_OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.tif +step +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84"}

            input_raster = gdal.Open(tif_in)
            
            self.reprojected_tif = tif_out + "_reprojected.tif"
            warp = gdal.Warp(self.reprojected_tif, input_raster, **kwargs)
            warp.FlushCache()
```

What would be causing the above error in python when it runs ok in the GDAL command window?